# Conflict between GNU parallel and awk (split a column and filter some rows)

Tags: awk, gnu-parallel

I am working on many large gz file like the below examples (only the first 5 rows are showed here).

```
gene_id variant_id  tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se
ENSG00000223972.4   1_13417_C_CGAGA_b37 1548    50  50  0.0766871   0.735446    -0.0468165  0.138428
ENSG00000223972.4   1_17559_G_C_b37 5690    7   7   0.00964187  0.39765 -0.287573   0.339508
ENSG00000223972.4   1_54421_A_G_b37 42552   28  28  0.039548    0.680357    0.0741142   0.179725
ENSG00000223972.4   1_54490_G_A_b37 42621   112 120 0.176471    0.00824733  0.247533    0.093081
```

Below is the output that I want.

Here, I split the second column by "_", and selected the rows based on the second and third columns (after splitting) ($2==1 and $3>20000). And I save it as a txt. The command below works perfectly.

```
zcat InputData.txt.gz | awk -F "_"  '$1=$1' | awk '{if ($2==1 && $3>20000) {print}}'  > OutputData.txt

ENSG00000223972.4   1 54421 A G b37 42552   28  28  0.039548    0.680357    0.0741142   0.179725
ENSG00000223972.4   1 54490 G A b37 42621   112 120 0.176471    0.00824733  0.247533    0.093081
```

But I want to use GNU parallel to speed up the process since I have many large gz files to work with. However, there seems to be some conflict between GNU parallel and awk, probably in terms of the quotation?

I tried defining the awk option separately as below, but it did not give me anything in the output file.

In the below command, I am only running the parallel on one input file. But I want to run in on multiple input files, and save multiple output files each corresponding to one input file.

For example,

InputData_1.txt.gz to OutputData_1.txt

InputData_2.txt.gz to OutputData_2.txt

```
awk1='{ -F "_"  "$1=$1" }'
awk2='{if ($2==1 && $3>20000) {print}}' 
parallel "zcat {} | awk '$awk1' |awk '$awk2' > OutputData.txt" ::: InputData.txt.gz
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on this task?
Thank you very much.

---

According to the suggestion from @karakfa, this is one solution

```
chr=1
RegionStart=10000
RegionEnd=50000
zcat InputData.txt.gz | awk -v chr=$chr -v start=$RegionStart -v end=$RegionEnd '{split($2,NewDF,"_")} NewDF[1]==chr && NewDF[2]>start && NewDF[2]<end {gsub("_"," ",$2) ; print > ("OutputData.txt")}' 

#This also works using parallel

awkbody='{split($2,NewDF,"_")} NewDF[1]==chr && NewDF[2]>start && NewDF[2]<end {gsub("_"," ",$2) ; print > ("{}_OutputData.txt")}'
parallel "zcat {} | awk -v chr=$chr -v start=$RegionStart -v end=$RegionEnd '$awkbody' " ::: InputData_*.txt.gz
```

The output file name for the input file `InputData_1.txt.gz` will be `InputData_1.txt.gz_OutputData.txt`

Comment: not regarding paralle, but you don't have to use two awks, you can let `_` or `whitespaces`  be the FS of awk.

Comment: I tried this ``awk -F "_"  '$1=$1' '{if ($2==1 && $3>20000) {print}}' ``, but it did not work as the two awk

Comment: Trying to use awk scripts stored in variables is far more likely to be the problem than some interaction between parallel and awk. Have you tried executing `zcat {} | awk '$awk1' |awk '$awk2'` without parallel? How did that go? Once you fixed the quotes around the variables to be double instead of single to let them expand then how did it go? Once you iteratively fixed those problems THEN try running it with parallel.

Comment: Agree with comments above, but you commented ***I tried this awk -F "_" '$1=$1'*** .. did you mean `$2==1` as in your code above? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it is `$1=$1`, this is to specify which column to split by "_"

Comment: @EdMorton, you are right. awk '$awk1' without parallel does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#QUOTING concludes:

> **Conclusion:** To avoid dealing with the quoting problems it may be easier just to write a small script or a function (remember to export -f the function) and have GNU parallel call that.

So:

```
doit() {
  zcat "$1" |
    awk -F "_"  '$1=$1' |
    awk '{if ($2==1 && $3>20000) {print}}'
}
export -f doit
parallel 'doit {} > {=s/In/Out/; s/.gz//=}' ::: InputData*.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing this is with `split`

```
$ awk '{split($2,f2,"_")} 
   f2[1]==1 && f2[2]>20000 {gsub("_"," ",$2); print > (FILENAME".output")}' file
```

however, if you provide data though stdin, `awk` won't capture a filename to write to.  You need to pass it to the script as a variable perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to combine the filter into single `awk` script, than and only than parallel can work.

Here is a sample solution that scan the whole `input.txt` only once (twice the performance):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ]*[_]?"}$2==1 && $7 > 20000 {print}' input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

`BEGIN{FS="[ ]*[_]?"}` Make the field separator multiple " " **or** "_"

`$2==1 && $7 > 20000 {print}` Print only lines with 2nd field == 1 and 7nt field > 2000

Sample debug script:

```
BEGIN{FS="[ ]*[_]?"}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf("$%d=%s%s",i, $i, OFS);
    print "";
}
$2==1 && $7 > 20000 {print}
```

Produce:

```
$1=gene $2=id $3=variant $4=id $5=tss $6=distance $7=ma $8=samples $9=ma $10=count $11=maf $12=pval $13=nominal $14=slope $15=slope $16=se 
$1=ENSG00000223972.4 $2=1 $3=13417 $4=C $5=CGAGA $6=b37 $7=1548 $8=50 $9=50 $10=0.0766871 $11=0.735446 $12=-0.0468165 $13=0.138428 
$1=ENSG00000223972.4 $2=1 $3=17559 $4=G $5=C $6=b37 $7=5690 $8=7 $9=7 $10=0.00964187 $11=0.39765 $12=-0.287573 $13=0.339508 
$1=ENSG00000223972.4 $2=1 $3=54421 $4=A $5=G $6=b37 $7=42552 $8=28 $9=28 $10=0.039548 $11=0.680357 $12=0.0741142 $13=0.179725 
ENSG00000223972.4   1_54421_A_G_b37 42552   28  28  0.039548    0.680357    0.0741142   0.179725
$1=ENSG00000223972.4 $2=1 $3=54490 $4=G $5=A $6=b37 $7=42621 $8=112 $9=120 $10=0.176471 $11=0.00824733 $12=0.247533 $13=0.093081 
ENSG00000223972.4   1_54490_G_A_b37 42621   112 120 0.176471    0.00824733  0.247533    0.093081
```